# Matching a string against contents of an array with regex operator not working

Tags: bash

i make a simply bash script to change number version based on the source branch of a merge request, i need increment different value if a feature or a hotfix/bigfix/fix branches names:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [  $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo -e "\nUsage: $0 MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE\n"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -f version ]; then
    echo "0.0.0" > version
fi

VERSION=$(cat version)
MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE=$1
declare -a FEATURE_LIST=("feature")
declare -a HOTFIX_LIST=("fix" "hotfix" "bugfix")

IFS="."
read -a num <<< ${VERSION}
MAJOR=${num[0]}
FEATURE=${num[1]}
HOTFIX=${num[2]}

if [[ ${MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE} =~ .*${FEATURE_LIST[*]}.* ]]; then
    FEATURE=$((${FEATURE}+1))
    echo "${MAJOR}.${FEATURE}.${HOTFIX}" > version
elif [[ ${MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE} =~ .*${HOTFIX_LIST[*]}.* ]]; then
    HOTFIX=$((${HOTFIX}+1))
    echo "${MAJOR}.${FEATURE}.${HOTFIX}" > version
else
    echo -e "Nothing change, exit."
    exit 0
fi
```

I've declared two arrays, `FEATURE_LIST` that contain only `feature` and work, if i type `./script.sh feature` or `./script.sh feature/foobar` it increase the value, instead if i type `./script.sh hotfix` or other values combinations of array `HOTFIX_LIST` nothing happened. Where the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.*${HOTFIX_LIST[*]}.*` is quite a tedious way of representing a string for an alternate match for the regex operator in `bash`. You can use the `|` character to represent alternations (because Extended Regular Expressions library is supported) in `bash` regex operator.

First generate the alternation string from the array into a string

```
hotfixList=$(IFS="|"; printf '^(%s)$' "${HOTFIX_LIST[*]}")
echo "$hotfixList"
^(fix|hotfix|bugfix)$
```

The string now represents a regex pattern comprising of three words that will match exactly as is because of the anchors `^` and `$`.

You can now use this variable in your regex match

```
[[ ${MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE} =~ $hotfixList ]]
```

also for the `feature` check, just put the whole array expansion with `[*]` on the RHS which would be sufficient. Also you don't need the greedy matches, since you have the longer string on the LHS the comparison would still hold good.

```
[[ ${MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE} =~ ${FEATURE_LIST[*]} ]]
```

As a side note, *always* use lower case variable names for user variables. The uppercase names are reserved only for the variables maintained by the shell which are persistent and have special meaning.